# Windows Phone 8 AAC File Sync issue

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, audio-streaming, aac

I want to stream an audio file that type is aac. when i play an aac file,I heard same voice different times on WP8 and WP8 is hanging back. I dont see that problem IOS and Android. Do you have any idea? How can i solve this sync. problem. Thanks

Comment: You mean you notice lag between the source and the receiver of the stream? That's to be expected in most systems.

Comment: i start same aac file android device and wp8 device , wp8 device progressing slowly, For example at 2:30  , i  heard different sounds.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - You're streaming an AAC file to Android and WP8, and after some period of time the WP8 stream seems to lag behind? Have you tried timing the stream in WP8 and seeing if it's really longer? Depending on the media player, WP8 may just be buffering more than Android, which would definitely cause this.